# wordpress plugin "Redirection" disables wp default behaviour of old url redirect to new one of post. how to stop it

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I used wp Redirect Plugin on my wp website for url masking and it works fine for this purpose however it has stopped wordpress default behaviour of redirecting old urls to new urls in case of post url change. And my old post urls that were redirecting to new urls that i changed before installing this plugin suddenly stoped redirecting and showing 404 page. And after disabling this plugin they again start to redirect normally. I think this plugin has stopped wordpress default behaviour which is not acceptable at all.

I want it to stop disabling wordpress default behaviour. How could i do this. Please provide me some help about it as i already created so many rules using this plugin and it will be difficult for me to remove this plugin suddenly.

Thanks